# Сокеты (websocket) в IE6, реализация возможна?

Tags: сокет, internet-explorer, websocket, webbrowser, browsers

Ради спортивного интереса задался этим вопросов. Что если браузер не поддерживает `websocket` и `COMET` не прокатывает? Какие решения существуют?

*P.S Тема использования сокетов не раскрывается в данном вопросе.*

Answer (score 3):

Есть такой разработчик `Alvaro Videla`, который написал библиотеку [gifsockets](https://github.com/videlalvaro/gifsockets) и использует GIF формат в качестве транспорта.

> Идея в том, что в формате анимированного GIF'а не указывается
>   количество фреймов, так что после отображения картинки браузер ждёт
>   новых фреймов с сервера до тех пор, пока не получит сигнальные биты о
>   конце файла. Другими словами, сервер может пушить в браузер сообщения
>   по открытому каналу в GIF.

После прочтения [данной статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/151538/) мой мозг взорвался, для тех кто не осведомлен хотелось поделиться, параноикам пригодится :)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket есть реализация на флэш, работает нормально